# Converting FILE * to CMemFile (or retrieving void* from FILE *)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, io

I'm currently working with a function call that uses FILE *, but I need to get data from the FILE * into a buffer without letting the data touch the HDD.  My first idea was to convert FILE * to a CMemFile, but I cannot find a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Using MFC...

This question comes up from using the JPEG library by IJG whose homepage can be found here: http://www.ijg.org/

Comment: What ways did you try and where did they fail?

Comment: What "date" do you need from the `FILE *`? The `FILE *` is simply a pointer to some structure inside the C runtime library. You can use it [if valid] to do I/O to a file, but as such the `FILE *` itself does not contain the content of the file [unless some read operations has been done, and the file is small enough to fit inside the cache inside `FILE *`].

Comment: I had not yet tried anything but trying to fetch the data using the FILE's members which I could find little information about.

Comment: You use functions such as `fread()` to do that. A `FILE *` is not like a class that has "members" which you can call....

Comment: @MatsPetersson - I'm working with a JPEG library that seems to be using the FILE struct to do it's writing to.  I want to get that data from the FILE * into a buffer.  This brings up an interesting point though, and I will probably look more into how the writing is actually being done.

Comment: Any chance you could add (in the original question, as comments tend to get overlooked at times) which jpeg library you are using - a link to its homepage would help.

Comment: You cannot use the FILE* as a object. It's an opaque data structure for reading/writing to from/to a file. Every implementation of the FILE structure is different and you cannot make any assumptions about it's content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setvbuf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to make a `FILE` pointer use a predefined (and filled) buffer.